# CSV file matplotlib.pyplot graphing error

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, export-to-csv

I am using pandas to import a csv to my notebook, and I changed any blank data column to a blank space. When I use plt.plot to make a graph of the data it turns out with a bunch of black lines on the x and y axis. Below is my code and graph:

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np
    %matplotlib inline

    apo2data = pd.read_csv('/Users/lilyloyer/Desktop/Apo2excel.csv')
    apo2data.isnull()
    data = apo2data.fillna(" ")

    teff=data['Teff (K)']
    grav=data['logg_seis']
    plt.plot(teff, grav, 'ro')
```

[image: plt.plot of teff and gravity]

Comment: The black lines are the axes ticks and the axes tick labels.  How many ticks are you drawing?

Comment: Im only trying to plot Effective temp vs gravity and have the x and y axis be the data points, in which the ranges respectively are 4000-6000, and 0-5. Sorry not sure how many ticks I am drawing, not the best coder

Comment: Try adding `plt.yticks((0,1,2,3,4,5)); plt.xticks((4000,5000,6000))`  after `plt.plot(...)` but in the same cell.  Also, if you use `plt.plot(teff, grav, 'r.')` the appearance of your plot will improve...

Comment: OTOH what Matplotlib is doing (wrt the deluge of ticks and tick labels) is very strange and totally unexpected.